# Error setting up OData/Content Delivery Web Service

Tags: 2011, odata

I have been setting up the OData Content Delivery for SDL Tridion 2011 and on a 64 bit environment. I am trying to host it in IIS but not able to browse the `odata.svc`. No error as such is shown on the browser, but in the back-end the app pool got stopped after some time. In the windows event log, I can see the error as shown below:

```
Faulting application name: w3wp.exe, version: 8.5.9600.16384, time stamp: 0x5215df96
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.3.9600.17415, time stamp: 0x54505737
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x0000000000008b9c
Faulting process id: 0xc5c
Faulting application start time: 0x01d0d5ad25ad1ece
Faulting application path: c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: 64f4a4a8-41a0-11e5-80bb-000d3ab06566
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you use the pre-built Web Service role that is shipped with Content Delivery, or did you "build it" yourself?

Comment: I am using the pre-built one

Comment: do you see any other .NET related warnings in the event log before this error ?

Comment: Are you installing on IIS 8.5 `version: 8.5.9600.16384` and SDL Tridion 2011 ? It is not supported I believe and the issue could be very well related that .net + IIS 8.5 + Win OS..

Comment: do you see any error in IIS logs?

Comment: @RamG: Thank you so much....I am indeed in this deadly combination - SDL 2011 + IIS 8.5.9600.16384 + Windows Server

Is there any document for this?

Comment: @RamG I think you should make that an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: It looks like the issue - Will check once the Client sets their server right and I will mark it as answer :)

Comment: @Ram: indeed it was the reason you specified and I agree it is a deadly combination and won't work. Changing it to the recommended environment works - If you can move your comment as an Answer, I will mark it as an accepted answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you are installing on IIS 8.5 version: 8.5.9600.16384 and SDL Tridion 2011 ? It is not supported I believe and the issue could be very well related the combination of .net + Juggernet + IIS 8.5 + Win OS .

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend checking the following:

1. Check if IIS is configured to stop app pool if not in use for some time period.
2. Using WinDbg to find out which area of the application is erroring out and parsing through app crash logs to find out areas of error
3. Check the worker process thread and its memory consumption in IIS after app pool restart and monitor if the usage goes high.
4. Also, check the CPU utilization on the machine to see if it is very high

Either one of the above should lead you in the right direction to solve the issue

Comment: Thanks Vipin; already checked these items and all seems good

Comment: What error do you get when you try to browse odata.svc?

Comment: No Error on browser.

Answer (score 0):

can you check the cd_core log file of the odata webservice? I would expect that it logs any errors/warnings in that log file (preferably in debug mode).

Comment: no error/warning logs in it